# Vba code in access that loops through all excel files in a folder, opens, saves and closes them

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am working on a vba script that I can deploy in Access that opens, saves and closes all excel files in a certain folder.

So far I have this code, which is kind of working, but has some issue. One is that it actually visibly opens excel and after the loop is done an empty, kind of weird looking excel is still open. With this I also noticed that in the taskmanager under processes this will result in running excel processes even though no excel instance is open.

Secondly since the format is xls I was dealing with the excel compatibility mode, not sure if I found the best solution for that as I sometimes get the error message afterwards now that the file extension and format is not the same.

Also I am just looking for some general improvements to the code as is.

This is my code:

```
Sub demo()
Dim directory As String, fileName As String
Dim Mywb As Workbook
Dim app As New Excel.Application
app.Visible = True
directory = "C:\Users\test\FolderA\"
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xls")

Do While fileName <> ""
Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)
fileName = Dir()
ActiveWorkbook.CheckCompatibility = False
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: app.Quit at the end to close the Excel application.

Comment: Disable screen updating with `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and toggle back on at end. Will make this run smoother and is cleaner from a user stand point.

Comment: @QHarr sorry for the unclear communication, I dont receive this error in the vba, if I open some of the excel files that are looped in this code I get the error message "The file format and extension dont match.. file could be corrupt" and so on.

Comment: @QHarr this is when manually opening. And also only after running the Open, Close, Save process.

Comment: I am researching to see if this is a known issue. I haven't experienced this before.

Comment: @QHarr You helped out a lot already! Thank you.

Comment: This is for some, but not all, files processed in this manner? Is there any pattern to those files affected?

Comment: @QHarr I have not been able to determine a pattern and it only happened to 1 file, so maybe just an anomaly. On a different note, I noticed that trying to apply this code to a shared network drive is behaving differently and not working as intended. In my case it asks me for every single file in a popup window on excel if I want to replace the file and after pressing yes for every single one, none of them have actually been opened and closed according to the timestamp. Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: You may need to do some googling on shared drive problems as I know things can get wonky in that regard. If I have time, I will have a look later.

Answer (score 2):

I will address the "weird" looking Excel.

You want `app.Quit` at the end to ensure you close the opened Excel application.

If you don't, you will end up with a performance drop and eventual crashes as your resources are tied up with unclosed application instances.

Comment: @QHarr Thanks for the quick input this is exactly what I was missing! On a related note I also noticed that in the taskmanager under processes afterwards I have a running excel process is this also a result of this? If yes how do I ensure this is not happening?

Comment: Potentially if you don't have once running a current workbook. Always a good idea to check from time to time and close an unnecessary.